# Convert a byte array to single bits in a array [Python 3.5]

Tags: python, arrays, hex, bit

I am looking for a operation witch converts my byte array:

```
mem = b'\x01\x02\xff'
```

in something like this:

```
[ [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] ]
```

These are operations that I tried:

```
import numpy as np

mem = b'\x01\x02\xff' #define my input
mem = np.fromstring(mem, dtype=np.uint8) #first convert to int

#print(mem) give me "[  1   2 255]" at this piont

mem = np.array(['{0:08b}'.format(mem[b]) for b in mem]) #now convert to bin
data= np.array([list(mem[b]) for b in mem]) #finally convert to single bits

print(data)
```

This code will crash at line 4.. `IndexError: index 255 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9`
Otherwise, it crash at line 5.. `IndexError: too many indices for array`

**These are my Questions:**

Why are the number of spaces different after the conversion from hex to int?

Is that the reason that my next conversion from int to bin failed?

Finally, what is wrong with my `list` operation?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Note that `mem[b]` should be `b` in the 2 statements: `mem = np.array(...)` and `data= np.array(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using unpackbits:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mem = b'\x01\x02\xff'
>>> x = np.fromstring(mem, dtype=np.uint8)
>>> np.unpackbits(x).reshape(3,8)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

#### Documentation

From `help(np.unpackbits)`:

> **unpackbits**(...)
>   unpackbits(myarray, axis=None)
>
> Unpacks elements of a uint8 array into a binary-valued output array.
>
> Each element of `myarray` represents a bit-field that should be unpacked
>   into a binary-valued output array. The shape of the output array is either
>   1-D (if `axis` is None) or the same shape as the input array with unpacking
>   done along the axis specified.

Comment: This is a unbelievable fast operation!! Great! 
I need this conversion for a huge amount of data and the results are now fantastic. 
My way to convert the data needs 100 times longer. God to know, that ´unpackbits´ works also well.

Answer (score 0):

To solve IndexError you can use  [`numpy.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy.ndindex):

```
import numpy as np

mem = b'\x01\x02\xff' #define my input
mem = np.fromstring(mem, dtype=np.uint8) #first convert to int

#print(mem) give me "[  1   2 255]" at this piont
mem=np.array(['{0:07b}'.format(mem[b]) for b in np.ndindex(mem.shape)])

data= np.array([list(mem[b]) for b in np.ndindex(mem.shape)]) #finally convert to single bits

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'] ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

Comment: Great! Have you any idea what the different numbers of spaces means? (line 6 in your code)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the problem with your code is that you're assuming the `int` in each item in the list will become 8 bits (so `2` will, in your assumption, return `00000010`). But it doesn't (`2` = `10`), and that screws up your code.

For your last two lines, I think this should be fine:

```python
data = [list(str(bin(x))[2:]) for x in mem]
for a in range(len(data)):
    while len(data[a]) < 8:
        data[a] = "0" + data[a]
```

`str(bin(x))[2:]` converts to binary (because it returns `0b1` for `1`, you need to use `[2:]` to get `1`).

The last chunk of code is to "pad" out your numbers with extra `0`'s.

Answer (score 0):

```
mem = b'\x01\x02\xff'
[[int(digit) for digit in "{0:08b}".format(byte)] for byte in mem]
```

outputs:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question.